# Pandas data assignment with NaN's failed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Has someone an idea why the following code is not working corret and converts the 5.0 to an integer 5? Without the np.nan the code works correct, but with the np.nan included not!

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5.0,np.nan], "B":[2.0,3.0]})
def casting(x):
    if math.isnan(x):
        return x
    else:
        y = int(x)
        return y
    
df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: casting(x))
print(df)```

   A    B
0  5.0  2.0
1  NaN  3.0
````

Comment: You can't have NaNs in a column of integers. You can however use the nullable integer dtype. Try to `.convert_dtypes()` or `.astype('Int64')`.

Comment: `np.nan` or `NULL` or `NaN` is always considered as float in a programming language. If required, you can `df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(0)` and then convert the field to integer. However, imputation of values must be done statistically for best results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I did not really understand why nan has type float. For me this makes no sense. I also found a way by using pd.NA.